# Arduino LED driver usage

Tags: arduino, led-driver

I try to use my Arduino Uno for managing 16 RGB LEDs therefore I want to use a breakout board for a PCA9685. It needs 5V and the Arduino has a pin with 5V, but I didn't find some specification how much mA it delivers? For the LEDs I need 16 × 20mA I think?

But I'm an absolute newbie in electronics.
What should I read to learn it by myself?

Comment: [The Art of Electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics) is usually a pretty good start.

Comment: The maximum current from the 5 V regulator output pin will be given in the datasheet. Did you check it?  RGB LEDs have three LEDs in each. If you've got 16 RGBs then you've got 48 LEDs. Note that the LEDs don't need tightly regulated voltage and could, for example, run from the power supply feeding _into_ the Arduino - a 9 V supply perhaps. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar if you want to add a schematic of your design.

Comment: The Arduino has an onboard regulator. IF the spec sheet does not tell you the available current then the specifications of the regulator should allow you to determine the maximum current available for use by a combination of the Arduino proper plus any external load. Usally "a few hundred mA" may be available BUT this is not certain.

Answer (score 1):

Do not load the regulator to be on safer side. Instead, time multiplex 16 leds using 4to16 bit decoder. Then, there will be no such current requirement problem.

As long as intensity of light doesn't matter, time multiplexing works.

Comment: This isn't quite true. When multiplexing the LEDs have to be driven at much higher current to give the same appearance as a normal continuously powered LED. For example, an LED rated at 20 mA might have a 100 mA pulse rating. This means that the current  requirement won't be reduced. You need to cover this in your answer. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: The application doesn't demands certain intensity of light otherwise what you've said it's true. But, if it's for indication purpose, still loading led with 20m will work which reduces the current.

Comment: Fair enough. At least edit your post to explain the reduction in intensity.

Comment: Don't derate my answer. Please remove that derating.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is given in the datasheet.

Output current on any led is 25mA absolute maximum. Somewhere in the datasheet, it was specified that you should only draw the 25mA when using the controller as a sink or totem pole. Otherwise, you are only allowed to draw 10mA max.

I advise you should make sure not to draw up to the 25mA absolute maximum rating since the device could get damaged.

If you feel like getting more current for some reason, you may want to use powerful drivers like the uln2003. If you want a powerful current source, you can use the udn2981A.

All these ICs are very easy to use. all you have to do is power them up by connecting their vcc and ground appropriately and applying your signals. You will need the datasheet to know which pin is which though.

Here is the link to the PCA9685 datasheet grabbed from Adafruit website:
https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/PCA9685.pdf

Comment: Good answer, but in the future please specify which datasheet your writing about. It avoids any confusion when multiple IC's are mentioned and there are many answers. Yes, it is about the Arduino Uno, but you need to make it clear. Others who review answers like the details spelled out for them.

Comment: @Sparky256 Instead of getting busy down-voting answer you claim is good, you can do a lot of people some good either by giving a better one or editing the existing answer. The trick is to encourage people to answer questions. Be nice.

Comment: I did not dv you, but many review answers and someone thought it was wrong or at least not a clear answer. Be careful of doing our thinking for us. Best to learn by example, produce better answers, and get upvotes instead of dowvotes.

Comment: I got also a downvote on the question and dont know why? -.-

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino has an onboard regulator.
A 'genuine' Arduino will have specifications available.
'Clones' *legally allowed but not necessarily identical) may not.

IF the specification sheet does not tell you the available current then the specifications of the regulator should allow you to determine the maximum current available for use by a combination of the Arduino proper plus any external load.

Usually "a few hundred mA" may be available BUT this is not certain.